# Flutter, late initialisation of VideoPlayerController from chewie package

Tags: flutter, video-player

I'm using chewie package to display and manage the presenting video. I need to initialise VideoPlayerController in event that comes to app when video presenting has been started (it returns me the url for the video presentation, I can pass it to the VideoPlayerController.network(url)). But it throws me an error on the start that variable is not initialised before starting the presentation (which is obvious). Is there a way to initialise this as an empty object and override it later or something like that?
The late variable is needed, because it is used in few places in app, like initState and build methods.

Part of code that can be helpful to understand what I mean:

```
late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

@override
void initState() {
  _onVideoPresentationChangeSubscription = instance
        .videoPresentation
        .onVideoPresentationChange()
        .listen((event) {
      if (event.type == VideoPresentationEventNames.videoPresentationStarted) {
          videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(url)..initialize();
      }
  });
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
        showControls: false,
      );

    final playerWidget = Chewie(
        controller: chewieController,
    );

return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: playerWidget,
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/chewie/blob/master/example/lib/app/app.dart

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your controller inside the initState override. Then in the build method you should conditionally render the Chewie player only when the controller exists and the videoPlayerController value is initialized. During the time the videoPlayerController is not ready simply show a loading widget.

```dart
...

late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController; 
late ChewieController chewieController;

@override
void initState() {
  _onVideoPresentationChangeSubscription = instance
        .videoPresentation
        .onVideoPresentationChange()
        .listen((event) {
      if (event.type == VideoPresentationEventNames.videoPresentationStarted) {
          videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(url)..initialize();
      }
  });
  initChewieController();
  super.initState();
}

void initChewieController() {
// Make sure this gets called once the videoPlayerController is initialized!!
  setState(() {
    chewieController = ChewieController(...);
  });
}

...
return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
      child: chewieController != null && chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized ? AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: Chewie(
         controller: chewieController, 
        ),
      ) : CircularProgressIndicator();
    );
```